# Hotspot mikrotik api, enrredado con eso

Tags: php, api

Ayuda por favor traté de adaptar este codigo a lo que necesito pero no se donde esta la falla, por favor necesito orientarme estoy enrredado:
aqui dejo el codigo que estoy usando, Gracias

```
<?php
    include("abrir_conexion.php");
      
     $name = $_POST["name"]; // Ususario que cargaremos
     $profile=    "1Hora";  // nombre del perfil
     $timelimit = "01:00:00"; // tiempo
     $comment= "1HORA"; // comentario

      if(isset($_POST['btn_1Hora']))
      {      
        if( $name != "" && $profile != ""  ){
    $API = new routeros_api();
    $API->debug = false;
    if ($API->connect($ServerList, $Username, $Pass, $Port)) {
       $API->write("/ip/hotspot/user/print",false);
       $API->write('?name='.$name,false);
       $API->write('?profile='.$profile,true);

       $READ = $API->read(false);
       $ARRAY = $API->parse_response($READ); // busco si ya existe
        if(count($ARRAY)>0){ 
            echo "Error: Ya existe " . $name ." en el perfil: ".$profile;
        }else{ // si no existe lo creo
            $API->write("/ip/hotspot/user/add",false);
            $API->write('=name='.$name,false);   // usuario
            $API->write('=profile='.$profile,false);        // perfil
            $API->write('=limit-uptime='.$timelimit,false); //tiempo
            $API->write('=comment='.$comment,true); // comentario            
            $READ = $API->read(false);
            $ARRAY = $API->parse_response($READ);            
        }
        $API->disconnect();
    }
}
      }

  ?>
```

Comment: *"adaptar este codigo a lo que necesito"* y ¿Qué necesitas?. *"no se donde esta la falla"* ¿Cómo sabes que falla?. Precisamente para diagnosticar se suele hacer `$API->debug = true;`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo un codigo que envia al address-lit y me trabaja perfecto ese fue el que adapté a este que necesito, pero este no me envia ningun dato.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.